# How do I kill a Python script in Java?

Tags: java, python, linux

I am launching a Python script in Java using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python myWebService.py")` and I am not doing anything else with it in Java. However, now I need to terminate the process from within my Java application. I've tried issuing a `pkill` command from the terminal, outside of the application, and this will not kill the script. Finding the pid in the terminal and then executing a `kill pid` does work from the terminal, but I have not found a way to get the pid of the process I started in Java. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python myWebService.py")` call returns a [process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html), that has a `destroy()` method to kill it. You can use that:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python myWebService.py")
process.destroy()
```

Comment: If that fixes your problem you should accept the answer!